# WP8 Playing audio under lock screen

Tags: audio, background, windows-phone-8

I see apps like white noise, and sleep that play audio and the audio continues to play after the screen has been locked.  The applications do not use the WP audio playback agent as the universal volume control does not become available.

I am trying to recreate said functionality but every thread I read is either about the WP audio playback agent or UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled, neither of which recreate what I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer minutes after I posted but SO wouldnt let me answer my own question.

ApplicationIdleDetectionMode  = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled did the trick.

Comment: This is a terrible solution and I doubt it will pass certification.

Comment: Well, thanks for your input, but it worked and passed certification months ago.

Comment: also, feels free to provide your better solution if you think mine is so terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the background `AudioPlayerAgent` and set the `PlayerControls` on the `AudioTrack` to `EnabledPlayerControls.None`.

[EnabledPlayerControls Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.enabledplayercontrols%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I can't check right now, this may just disable them but it's another option.

Answer (score 0):

> The applications do not use the WP audio playback agent

Seems you already known the answer. If you want to play audio under the lock screen, you have the use the Audio Playback Agent.